# IIS no genera log en aplicación con .net core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis

Actualmente tengo desplegada en una maquina virtualcon IIS una aplicación desarrollada en c# con.net core 2.2.

el problema es qeu no genera logs

ya la carpeta logs tiene permisos y en el web config esta relacionada la ruta pero continua sin generar logs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tienes que habilitar a true stdoutLogEnabled="true"

Comment: perfecto muchas gracias no se como se me paso

Comment: Si, lo que pasa que vuelve a false, cuando publicas, debe haber una forma para que quede en true por defecto

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53914112/asp-net-core-web-config-publish

Comment: Super !!! quedo full